# How can I detect my graphics card with no driver installed?

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, graphics

I have no idea what graphics card hardware do I have, and have no driver installed. How can I detect what graphics card do I have to install the right driver?

Comment: What your operating system?

Answer (score 6):

For Windows I would see if Slimdrivers can autodetect it first otherwise try this.

Device Manger->Display Adapter
Right click on the device and click properties.
Click on the details tab.
Use the drop down to select:"Hardware Ids"
Ven is short for vendor so ATI/AMD, nvidia, Intel are the most common.
Dev is the device ID.

google   Dev #### and Ven ####
You should be able to find it.

Comment: If you have the vendor and/or device ID go to → http://www.pcidatabase.com

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the output of `dmesg` or `lspci` or `lsusb` (if it is a USB video card).

For me, I get the following:

```
> lspci | grep -i vga
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GT218 [ION] (rev a2)
```